# What is the number of weekly tables that generate the most profit?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

> A cabinetmaker designs and sells $q$ wooden tables per week. The relation $p=125\frac{\ln(q)}{q}$ is the price, in dollars, when $q$ tables are demanded. The average cost of producing $q$ units is:
> $C(q)=\frac{q^2}{3}$ with $2\leq q\leq 9$
>
> What is the number of weekly tables that generate the most profit?

In order to find the maximum value of $U$, the critical points are determined in the usual way and then its nature is investigated.

$I$ = income

$C$ = costs

$U$ = profit

$C'(q)=\frac{2q}{3}$

$I(q)=pq=125\frac{\ln(q)}{q}q$

$I'(q)=\frac{125}{q}$

$U'(q)=I'(q)-C'(q)$

$0=\frac{375-2q^2}{3q}$

$q=13.69$

Answer (score 0):

$C(q)$ is the average cost of producing $q$ units, so the total cost is $qC(q)=q^3/3$. The profit function is $125\ln q-q^3/3$ which maximizes at $q=5$.